# both if/else logic execute in sequence without a return false added?

Tags: javascript

both if/else logic execute in sequence without a return false added but when a return false is added, it works as normal, either if or else is executed but the code below it does not it executed, which is a problem..

```
  var TL = {
             displayInfo: function(sectionType, fileName)
                          {
                              if(sectionType == "sectionA")
                              {
                                   sectionType = "ListA";
                                   return false; // works as normal with this line
                              }else
                              {
                                   sectionType = "ListB";
                                    return false; // works as normal with this line
                              }     
                             // additional below that is not being executed when I add the return false in the if/else logic
                          }
            };
```

When I remove the return false statement in each if/else, both if/else execute. I have additional code in this method below the if/else logic that I would like to execute.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. If you don't want to `return` from the function from inside the condition blocks, then simply don't do that....

Comment: Without the return false statements located in the if/else blocks, both if/else statements get executed, which is a problem...

Comment: return means that you stop execution of the function and return some value to the caller. Of course when both paths if and else return, it is not possible to reach the code after it.

Comment: Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FWwTn/

Comment: The problem is why both if/else statements get executed when no return false statements are added in both if/else blocks? To me, either if or else should get executed not both, right?

Comment: I would challenge the premise that you're debugging it correctly...Seems quite impossible for both blocks to get executed

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: They don't. You're doing something else wrong. Arun has demonstrated that `if`/`else` function properly.

Comment: Arun P Johny, both are being executed using your example...

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: No, they're not... What is your browser? Perhaps you have a very poor browser that's reacting badly to your very poor layout of Javascript language constructs

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene they are most certainly NOT both being executed in the example!  Only the If block is run!

Comment: Sorry Arun P Johny, you're right. its working but I still have my problem

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: Use `@` notification syntax please. You've been here for 1 year 3 months and should know how to use Stack Overflow by now. Also, I can't see that there is any problem left to solve here, so please delete the question.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene Simply accept the only answer below.  It fixes your problem perfectly with the exception of commenting out sectionType = "ListA"; in the if block, which is required by your logic.

Comment: How are you using the method? The only possibility I see that both blocks would run is if you call the method twice with different `sectionType` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement takes the execution to the end of function and no code statement after return is executed. If you are returning false in both `if` and `else` then take the return statement out if `if-else`.

```
var TL = {
         displayInfo: function(sectionType, fileName)
                      {

                          if(sectionType == "sectionA")
                          {
                               sectionType = "ListA";
                               //return false; // works as normal with this line
                          }else
                          {
                               sectionType = "ListB";
                                //return false; // works as normal with this line
                          }     
                         // additional below that is not being executed when I add the return false in the if/else logic
                      }

                      //Your code
                     return false;
        };
```

If you have to return both false and true from condition if-else then you can use a variable to assign the return value. I have made a demo for your understand and practice, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uhXt3/)

Comment: I have this code without the return false but the problem is both if/else are being executed. Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: No, they're not, as we just discussed in the comments under your question. Why do you keep saying that they are?

Comment: @Adil you need to uncomment sectionType = "ListA";

Comment: How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I have made a demo for your understand and practice, here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uhXt3/

Answer (score 1):

I execute the below code and it works as expected:

```
var TL = {
    displayInfo: function (sectionType, fileName) {
        if (sectionType == "sectionA") {
            console.info("inside if");
            sectionType = "ListA";
        } else {
            console.info("inside else");
            sectionType = "ListB";
        }
        console.info(sectionType);
    }
};

TL.displayInfo("sectionA");
```

The code goes into if block and the last console log prints "ListA" as expected. I am not sure  about the problem. JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/poonia/eq9u3/1/

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably somewhere else in your code, I guess you create instances of displayInfo.

If you're using IE you can press F12, start debug and have console.log log messages proving that if and else aren't both executed unless you're calling it multiple times with different arguments.

Any other browser should support console.log and you can see the console usually by pressing F12

```
var TL = {
             displayInfo: function(sectionType, fileName)
console.log("displayInfo called");
                          {
                              if(sectionType == "sectionA")
                              {
console.log("sectionType = sectionA");
                                   sectionType = "ListA";
                                   return false; // works as normal with this line
                              }else
                              {
console.log("sectionType = listB");
                                   sectionType = "ListB";
                                    return false; // works as normal with this line
                              }     
                             // additional below that is not being executed when I add the return false in the if/else logic
                          }
            };
```